# How to use an external corpus in nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I need to make a named entity recognition program for college. I'm using nltk and python 2.7. The corpus I am using is Spanish that nltk has. There is a specific method tokenize this corpus in nltk and I did the whole program with this form of tokenization, but I want to use an external corpus now and wanted tokenize it in the same way, but I do not know how.

How nltk's method was tokenizing data:

> [(u'Melbourne', u'NP', u'B-LOC'), (u'(', u'Fpa', u'O'), (u'Australia',
>   u'NP', u'B-LOC'), (u')', u'Fpt', u'O'), (u',', u'Fc', u'O'), (u'25',
>   u'Z', u'O'), (u'may', u'NC', u'O'), (u'(', u'Fpa', u'O'), (u'EFE',
>   u'NC', u'B-ORG'), (u')', u'Fpt', u'O'), (u'.', u'Fp', u'O')]

A list for each sentence and each row is a tuple

And how i do it:

> [u'Melbourne', u'NP', u'B-LOC', u'(', u'Fpa', u'O', u'Australia',
>   u'NP', u'B-LOC', u')', u'Fpt', u'O', u',', u'Fc', u'O', u'25', u'Z',
>   u'O', u'may', u'NC', u'O', u'(', u'Fpa', u'O', u'EFE', u'NC',
>   u'B-ORG', u')', u'Fpt', u'O', u'.']

There is no tuple

The code I used:

```
f = io.open(train_corpus, 'r', encoding='utf8')
raw = f.read()
#my method
tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)]
train_sents = nltk.Text(tokens)
#nltk's method
train = list(nltk.corpus.conll2002.iob_sents('esp.train'))
#print results of two forms
print train_sents[0]
print 
print train[0]
```

Then I would like to know how tokenizer the program to stay the same as the tokenization method done by nltk for that corpus in another corpus.

Comment: First, use `python3` or in `python2` use `io.open(train_corpus, 'r', encoding='utf8')` to avoid decoding and encoding strings.

Comment: Can you also be clearer in explaining what you need? your examples are a mix of English and Spanish examples and it' unclear what you're trying to achieve =(

Comment: Also, you're reading a whole corpus as a single list of tokens and not sentences when you try to do `nltk.word_tokenize(corpus)`. you need to do something like `[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(corpus)]`.

Comment: It really was not very clear, I edited the content and changed the code with the comments you wrote. Take a look, is it clearer now? I do not write in English very well.